# (Grund)Schule anfangen, kommen or beginnen?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How do you say it? To start school.

> Schule anfangen.

> Schule kommen.

> Schule beginnen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For primary school, the most popular expression is:

> in die Schule kommen

It might sound a bit strange, but that's the common expession for starting school.

> Wann kommt deine Tochter denn in die Schule?
> Hanna kommt dieses Jahr in die Schule.

Ugly bureaucratic expressions:

> Einschulung
> eingeschult werden

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Ist das auch in Deutschland so? In Österreich gehen Schüler ja (sprachlich formuliert) nicht nur *»zur«* Schule, sondern auch hinein, also *»in die«* Schule, daher scheint es mir auch schlüssig zu sein, beim Schulstart zu sagen: *»Das Kind kommt in die Schule«.* Wenn Kinder aber üblicherweise (sprachlich) *»zur Schule«* gehen, passt es für mich irgendwie nicht zu sagen, dass sie mit 6 Jahren dann doch *»in die Schule«* kommen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "Zur Schule kommen" kann man hier (Westdeutschland) auf jeden Fall auch sagen, ich halte es für weniger gebräuchlich als "in die Schule kommen". Beweisen kann ich das aber auch nicht.

Comment: »zur Schule kommen« hat für mich (norddeutsch) nicht die Bedeutung der Einschulung, sondern nur die der Bewegung zur Schule.

Comment: _Mit der Schule anfangen_ finde ich auch akzeptabel -- oder ist das eine österreichische Einbildung?